# Data structure design: given set of week/day pairs, get adjacent days in set?

Tags: java, data-structures

I need a way to represent information about Weeks and Days as such:

```
W1: D1,D2
W2: D1,D5
W3: D3,D2
```

so that, given my current week and day, I should be able to get the previous day and next day

For ex:

```
if(currentDay = W2D5)
{
    prevDay = W2D1;
    nextDay = W3D3;
}
```

Here are two options I came up with:

1. Use a treemap

   TreeMap< Integer,TreeMap< Integer>>

In the outer tree map, store the week number as the key and in the inner tree map, store the

1. Use an array 
   [w1d1,w2d2,w2d1...]

What would be a good data structure to use for such a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just a well-ordered collection on a WeekDay type? (The WeekDay type includes a Week and a Day and provides well-defined ordering.)

If this were the case, `TreeSet<WeekDay>` could be used with [`higher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#higher%28E%29)/`lower` (or even `headSet/tailSet`).

```
TreeSet<WeekDay> days = ...;
WeekDay nextDay = days.higher(currentDay);
```

<del>Unfortunately `TreeSet<WeekDay>` (or `PriorityQueue`) and other standard data-types won't work because they *lack a method of iterating forward/back from a given element*. This isn't strictly true, at least `TreeMap` *can* be used, just with a `O(1)` manual look-up using the iterator: however, the required operations to take advantage of the `O(lg n)` access just aren't "standard" in a `TreeSet`.</del>

<del>This [article on Sorted Lists in Java](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/2010/12/sorted_lists_in_java/) covers a bunch of interesting things, as well as providing an implementation which could be adapted.</del>

Of course, it is also possible to just use an `ArrayList` and keep it [sorted](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) on update. In that case a [`Collections.binarySearch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29) can be used and the index for prev/next are easily provided :)

Happy coding.

Comment: OK, I've deleted my earlier comments, since they no longer make sense in the context of your corrected answer.

Answer (score 1):

i like enums:

```
class Pair {
    enum Day { mon,tue,wed,thu,fri;
        Day next() {
            return values()[(ordinal()+1)%days];
        }
        Day previous() {
            return values()[(days+ordinal()-1)%days];
        }
        static final int days=values().length;
    }
    enum Week { w1,w2,w3;
    Week next() {
        return ordinal()<weeks-1?values()[(ordinal()+1)]:null;
    }
    Week previous() {
        return ordinal()!=0?values()[(weeks+ordinal()-1)%weeks]:null;
    }
    static final int weeks=values().length;
    }
    Pair(Week week,Day day) {
        this.week=week;
        this.day=day;
    }
    Pair next() {
        if(day.ordinal()<Day.days-1)
            return new Pair(week,day.next());
        else return new Pair(week.next(),Day.mon);
    }
    Pair previous() {
        if(day.ordinal()>0)
            return new Pair(week,day.previous());
        else return new Pair(week.previous(),Day.fri);
    }
    public String toString() {
        if(week==null||day==null)
            return "*** ***";
        return week+" "+day;
    }
    final Day day;
    final Week week;
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(Pair.Week week:Pair.Week.values())
            for(Pair.Day day:Pair.Day.values()) {
                Pair pair=new Pair(week,day);
                System.out.println(pair.previous()+" "+pair+" "+pair.next());
            }
    }
}

*** *** w1 mon w1 tue
w1 mon w1 tue w1 wed
w1 tue w1 wed w1 thu
w1 wed w1 thu w1 fri
w1 thu w1 fri w2 mon
w1 fri w2 mon w2 tue
w2 mon w2 tue w2 wed
w2 tue w2 wed w2 thu
w2 wed w2 thu w2 fri
w2 thu w2 fri w3 mon
w2 fri w3 mon w3 tue
w3 mon w3 tue w3 wed
w3 tue w3 wed w3 thu
w3 wed w3 thu w3 fri
w3 thu w3 fri *** ***
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an `enum` like this

```
public enum WeekAndDay {
    W1D1(1, 1), W1D2(1, 2) // ...

    private int week;
    private int day;

    private WeekAndDay(int week, int day) {
        this.week = week; this.day = day;
    }
    ...
}
```

This has a natural ordering and can be used as a key in a `TreeMap`; e.g.

```
    TreeMap<WeekAndDay, Info> map = ...
```

or used to order a list of records (assuming that the records have a suitably declared key); e.g.

```
ArrayList<Info> records = ...
Collections.sort(records, new Comparator<Info>{
        public int compare(Info i1, Info i2) {
            return i1.getWeekAndDay().compareTo(i2.getWeekAndDay());
        }});
```

---

**FOLLOW UP**

> In my case, the number of weeks and days is not known upfront, so creating an enum wouldn't work.

(It *could* work is you made some assumptions / placed some limits on the number of WeekAndDay values are required ... but I guess you don;t want to do that.)

You could create a class that behaves like a sort of dynamic enum.

- No public constructor.
- A factory method that uses a map so that there is a unique instance for any week / day pair.
- An overloaded factory method that takes a String like `"W1D1"` as an argument.
- A `toString()` method that renders in `"W1D1"` format.

However, in general you **won't** be able to write code like this (taken from your question!):

```
if (currentDay == W2D5) {
    prevDay = W2D1;
    nextDay = W3D3;
}
```

This would require that your code explicitly declare a bunch of constants like this:

```
public static final WeekAndDay W2D5 = WeekAndDay.getInstance("W2D5"); 
public static final WeekAndDay W2D1 = WeekAndDay.getInstance("W2D1"); 
public static final WeekAndDay W3D3 = WeekAndDay.getInstance("W3D3");
```

In general, you can't do that for all week/day combinations if the number of days and weeks are not known upfront.

(OK, you *can* do that, but only if the set of constants that you want to *use* in your code is known upfront.  I'm discounting reflection here, because it would be a bad solution.)

Comment: In my case, the number of weeks and days is not known upfront, so creating an enum wouldn't work.